# Why i can not run python script by CDM ["python","server.py"] but can run manually

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

I build a docker container with python and anaconda env, all work without docker container.
Then a move that code to container, i got a problem with start that code and i got problem, my steps:

1. Docker container can not start by CMD ["python","server.py"], it not work because some module not found but i am sure that my conda env is perfect (see step 3)
2. I moved my code to server1.py and my server.py just `while True: pass`
3. I get in container by "docker exec -it  bash", i saw the conda env activated
4. I run "python server1.py" the code work perfectly

Why wrong with mycode?

Comment: Show your Dockerfile and the actual error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Your situation might because docker failed to activate the conda environment when build. Try remove the CMD part in your docker file then when you execute docker run, add:

```
 /bin/bash -c "conda run --no-capture-output -n your_env_name your_CMD_to_start_server"
```

For example:

```
docker run --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} \
  --restart unless-stopped  -d  \
  -it roi_updater:latest \
  /bin/bash -c "conda run --no-capture-output -n server_env python /root/source/start_server.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with Docker, it seems likely that it's not activating your conda env though. You could try asking for the required python interpreter explicitly.

To find it go inside your container and activate your conda env. `where python` should then give you the full path to the interpreter.

Use that path in your docker CMD instead of just `python`.

Comment: I had export my Pythonpath in to my source folder i am sure that is right Path by: 

WORKDIR "/source"
ENV PYTHONPATH /source:$PYTHONPATH